# How do I make a Twisted application handle SIGTERM?

Tags: python, twisted

I have the following sample code. The code for handling SIGINT works perfectly but it does not seem to be doing the same when I send a SIGTERM. What could be wrong?

```
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print 'Terminating...'
    reactor.removeAll()
    reactor.stop()

def run():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)
    site = server.Site(stuff)
    reactor.listenTCP(8080, site)
    reactor.run()
```

Why isn't SIGTERM calling signal_handler?

**Updated with the answer**
I added `reactor.addSystemEventTrigger('before', 'shutdown', shutdown)` before running the reactor and then called reactor.sigTerm() from the shutdown method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can only be one handler for a particular signal.  `reactor.run()` installs its own handler for `SIGTERM` that replaces yours.

Fortunately, the reactor's `SIGTERM` handler essentially does the same thing as yours (but more correctly).

Comment: Got it working, thanks. I've updated the question with the answer.

Comment: I'm confused by the update.  Why do you want to call the reactor's `sigTerm` method (an undocumented implementation detail)?

Comment: Without calling it, I am getting a whole bunch of tracebacks (possibly from the module I'm using).

It is documented here - http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/api/twisted.internet.base.ReactorBase.html#sigTerm

Comment: Yes... to do something other than what you're using it to do. :)  Also notice that that's documentation on `ReactorBase` - not on a reactor interface.  There's no guarantee that any particular reactor will have that random method.  I'm pretty sure you shouldn't need to call it (I have written lots of programs with Twisted and I have never once called `sigTerm` manually).  Perhaps the real problem here has a better solution?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize it was a dirty hack. It seems to be working in this application at least, but I'll look for the right approach. I'm very new to Twisted.